# How to specific key to be one of enum keys?

Tags: typescript

For example, to specify an object to have all keys in enum:

```
enum Sizes {
  Small = 'S',
  Medium = 'M',
  Large = 'L',
  ExtraLarge = 'XL',
}

/**
 * ️ let keys: {Small: any; Medium: any; Large: any; ExtraLarge: any}
 */
let keys: { [key in keyof typeof Sizes]: any };
```

But what if I only want an object with only one of the keys in enum?

```
/***
 *
 * let key: { Small: any } or {Medium: any} ..., but not {Small: any, Medium: any}
 */
let key: { [????]: any }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map and distribute the union of keys as follows:

```js
let key: { [K in keyof typeof Sizes]: { [_ in K]: any } }[keyof typeof Sizes]
```

for a type of

```js
| {
    Small: any;
  }
| {
    Medium: any;
  } 
| {
    Large: any;
  } 
| {
    ExtraLarge: any;
  }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAyglgL2AZygbwFBVhAhgG3ygF4oByGMgGiygFlgATOSE8u62gGVwCcBzYGzJdO2AKIAPAC69cPAUNJkAGqJoBfDBnzBpUANbAAngC50UANoBpKHBCGTAewBmUacYAOwV7EQoAXXM0KwB9OwdrIKhcEGMoDQTLI2NfD29feCRkAKA)